# Multiple lexor errors in console and code coming on screen after upgrading webpack, babel, angularjs versions

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, webpack, babeljs

Previous package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=dev PLATFORM=APP webpack-dev-server --config configFiles/dev/webpack.dev.js --open --watch --progress --colors",
    "build-dev": "NODE_ENV=dev PLATFORM=APP webpack --config configFiles/dev/webpack.dev.js --progress",
    "start-dev-enterprise": "NODE_ENV=dev PLATFORM=ENTERPRISE webpack-dev-server --config configFiles/dev/webpack.dev.js --open --watch --progress --colors",
    "build-dev-enterprise": "NODE_ENV=dev PLATFORM=ENTERPRISE webpack --config configFiles/dev/webpack.dev.js --progress",
    "start-stage": "NODE_ENV=dev PLATFORM=APP webpack-dev-server --config configFiles/stage/webpack.stage.js --open --watch --progress --colors",
    "build-stage": "NODE_ENV=prod PLATFORM=APP webpack --config configFiles/stage/webpack.stage.js --progress",
    "start-stage-enterprise": "NODE_ENV=dev PLATFORM=ENTERPRISE webpack-dev-server --config configFiles/stage/webpack.stage.js --open --watch --progress --colors",
    "build-stage-enterprise": "NODE_ENV=prod PLATFORM=ENTERPRISE webpack --config configFiles/stage/webpack.stage.js --progress",
    "start-prod": "NODE_ENV=prod PLATFORM=APP webpack-dev-server --env.prod --config configFiles/prod/webpack.prod.js --open --watch --progress --colors",
    "build-prod": "NODE_ENV=prod PLATFORM=APP webpack --config configFiles/prod/webpack.prod.js --progress",
    "start-prod-enterprise": "NODE_ENV=prod PLATFORM=ENTERPRISE webpack-dev-server --env.prod --config configFiles/prod/webpack.prod.js --open --watch --progress --colors",
    "build-prod-enterprise": "NODE_ENV=prod PLATFORM=ENTERPRISE webpack --config configFiles/prod/webpack.prod.js --progress",
    "start-lan": "NODE_ENV=dev webpack-dev-server --config configFiles/lan/webpack.lan.js --open --watch --progress --colors --port 8082 --host 0.0.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-minify-webpack-plugin": "^0.3.1",
    "babel-plugin-angularjs-annotate": "^0.9.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.26.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "0.1.17",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.7",
    "csv-loader": "2.1.1",
    "exports-loader": "0.6.4",
    "extract-loader": "1.0.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "1.1.5",
    "html-loader": "0.5.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.30.1",
    "imports-loader": "0.7.1",
    "node-sass": "4.6.0",
    "sass-loader": "6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "0.19.0",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "1.0.1",
    "url-loader": "0.6.2",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.7.2",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.1",
    "yarn": "1.17.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.6.6",
    "angular-animate": "1.6.7",
    "angular-file-upload": "^2.6.1",
    "angular-ui-mask": "1.8.7",
    "angular-ui-router": "0.4.3",
    "angular-ui-sortable": "0.17.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "bootstrap": "4.1.1",
    "bootstrap-daterangepicker": "2.1.30",
    "core-js": "^3.0.0-beta.3",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "file-saver": "1.3.3",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "jquery-ui": "1.12.1",
    "jquery-ui-touch-punch": "0.2.3",
    "moment": "2.20.1",
    "ng-idle": "1.3.2",
    "popper.js": "1.12.6",
    "promise-polyfill": "^8.1.0",
    "signature_pad": "3.0.0-beta.3",
    "strophe.js": "^1.3.5",
    "strophejs-plugin-disco": "0.0.2",
    "uuid": "^8.3.1"
  }
}
```

previous webpack.common.js

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const transformPlugin = require('babel-plugin-angularjs-annotate');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const MinifyPlugin = require("babel-minify-webpack-plugin");

const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry:{
        app: './app/app.js',
        vendor: ['angular', 'angular-ui-router', 'angular-ui-mask', 'ng-idle', 'jquery', 'angular-animate', 'bootstrap-daterangepicker',
            'angular-ui-sortable', 'angular-file-upload', 'jquery-ui-touch-punch']
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './app/index.html',
            inject: 'body',
            hash: true,
            excludeChunks: ['ie9libs'],
            //minify : true
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name : 'vendor',
            chunks : ['app', 'vendor']
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
            Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'],
            // In case you imported plugins individually, you must also require them here:
            Util: "exports-loader?Util!bootstrap/js/dist/util",
            Dropdown: "exports-loader?Dropdown!bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown"
        }),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            {
                from : './app/javascripts/sdk',
                to : 'sdk/'
            },
            {
                from : './app/assets/audio',
                to: 'assets/audio/'
            },
            {
                from: './app/assets/esign',
                to: 'assets/esign'
            },
            {
                from: './app/assets/pico',
                to: 'assets/pico'
            }
        ]),
    ],
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js?[hash]',
        chunkFilename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/javascripts/sdk')
                ],
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: [['es2015']],
                        "plugins": [transformPlugin]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(html)$/,
                include: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/templates')
                ],
                use: [
                    {
                        loader : 'file-loader',
                        options : {
                            name : '[name].[ext]',
                            outputPath: 'templates/',
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader : 'extract-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader : 'html-loader',
                        options : {
                            minimize: true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif|ico)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'url-loader',
                        options: {
                            fallback: 'file-loader',
                            limit: 500,
                            name: './images/[name].[ext]'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /facefinder/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                          name: '[name].[ext]',
                          outputPath: 'assets/pico/'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(mp3|wav|wma|aac|ogg)$/,
                include: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/assets/audio')
                ],
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                          name: '[name].[ext]',
                          outputPath: 'assets/audio/'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader : 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '[name].[ext]',
                            outputPath: 'fonts/',
                            publicPath: '../'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /ui-sortable/,
                use: ['imports-loader?$UI=jquery-ui/ui/widgets/sortable']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(csv|tsv)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader : 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name (file){
                                return  '[name].[ext]';
                            },
                            outputPath: 'csv/'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Previous Webpack.dev.js

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('../../webpack.common.js');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const config=require('./dev-config.js');

module.exports = merge(common, {
    devtool: 'eval',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist',
        //hot: true
    },
    plugins:[
        new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin(config)
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Updated package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=dev PLATFORM=APP webpack-dev-server --mode development --config configFiles/dev/webpack.dev.js --progress --color",
    "build-dev": "NODE_ENV=dev PLATFORM=APP webpack --config configFiles/dev/webpack.dev.js --progress",
    "start-dev-enterprise": "NODE_ENV=dev PLATFORM=ENTERPRISE webpack-dev-server --config configFiles/dev/webpack.dev.js --open --watch --progress --colors",
    "build-dev-enterprise": "NODE_ENV=dev PLATFORM=ENTERPRISE webpack --config configFiles/dev/webpack.dev.js --progress",
    "start-stage": "NODE_ENV=dev PLATFORM=APP webpack-dev-server --config configFiles/stage/webpack.stage.js --open --watch --progress --colors",
    "build-stage": "NODE_ENV=prod PLATFORM=APP webpack --config configFiles/stage/webpack.stage.js --progress",
    "start-stage-enterprise": "NODE_ENV=dev PLATFORM=ENTERPRISE webpack-dev-server --config configFiles/stage/webpack.stage.js --open --watch --progress --colors",
    "build-stage-enterprise": "NODE_ENV=prod PLATFORM=ENTERPRISE webpack --config configFiles/stage/webpack.stage.js --progress",
    "start-prod": "NODE_ENV=prod PLATFORM=APP webpack-dev-server --env.prod --config configFiles/prod/webpack.prod.js --open --watch --progress --colors",
    "build-prod": "NODE_ENV=prod PLATFORM=APP webpack --config configFiles/prod/webpack.prod.js --progress",
    "start-prod-enterprise": "NODE_ENV=prod PLATFORM=ENTERPRISE webpack-dev-server --env.prod --config configFiles/prod/webpack.prod.js --open --watch --progress --colors",
    "build-prod-enterprise": "NODE_ENV=prod PLATFORM=ENTERPRISE webpack --config configFiles/prod/webpack.prod.js --progress",
    "start-lan": "NODE_ENV=dev webpack-dev-server --config configFiles/lan/webpack.lan.js --open --watch --progress --colors --port 8082 --host 0.0.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.15.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "7.15.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.15.6",
    "babel-loader": "8.2.2",
    "babel-plugin-angularjs-annotate": "0.10.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "6.26.2",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "4.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "9.0.1",
    "css-loader": "6.2.0",
    "csv-loader": "3.0.3",
    "exports-loader": "3.0.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "6.2.0",
    "html-loader": "2.1.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "5.3.2",
    "imports-loader": "3.0.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.3.0",
    "node-sass": "6.0.1",
    "sass-loader": "12.1.0",
    "style-loader": "3.2.1",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "5.2.4",
    "url-loader": "4.1.1",
    "webpack": "5.52.1",
    "webpack-cli": "4.8.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "4.2.1",
    "webpack-merge": "5.8.0",
    "yarn": "2.4.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.8.2",
    "angular-animate": "1.8.2",
    "angular-file-upload": "^2.6.1",
    "angular-ui-mask": "1.8.7",
    "angular-ui-router": "1.0.29",
    "bootstrap": "4.6.0",
    "bootstrap-daterangepicker": "3.1.0",
    "core-js": "3.17.3",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "file-saver": "1.3.3",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "jquery-ui": "1.12.1",
    "jquery-ui-touch-punch": "0.2.3",
    "moment": "2.29.1",
    "ng-idle": "1.3.2",
    "popper.js": "1.16.1",
    "promise-polyfill": "^8.2.0",
    "signature_pad": "3.0.0-beta.4",
    "strophe.js": "^1.4.2",
    "strophejs-plugin-disco": "0.0.2",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  }
}
```

Updated webpack.common.js

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const transformPlugin = require('babel-plugin-angularjs-annotate');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const MinifyPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry:{
        app: './app/app.js',
        vendor: ['angular', 'angular-ui-router', 'angular-ui-mask', 'ng-idle', 'jquery', 'angular-animate', 'bootstrap-daterangepicker', 'angular-file-upload', 'jquery-ui-touch-punch']
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin({cleanAfterEveryBuildPatterns : ['dist']}),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './app/index.html',
            inject: 'body',
            hash: true,
            excludeChunks: ['ie9libs'],
            //minify : true
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
        // new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        //     name : 'vendor',
        //     chunks : ['app', 'vendor']
        // }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
            Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'],
            // In case you imported plugins individually, you must also require them here:
            Util: "exports-loader?Util!bootstrap/js/dist/util",
            Dropdown: "exports-loader?Dropdown!bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown"
        }),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin({
            patterns : [
                {
                    from : './app/javascripts/sdk',
                    to : 'sdk/'
                },
                {
                    from : './app/assets/audio',
                    to: 'assets/audio/'
                },
                {
                    from: './app/assets/esign',
                    to: 'assets/esign'
                },
                {
                    from: './app/assets/pico',
                    to: 'assets/pico'
                }
            ]
        }),
    ],
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js?[hash]',
        chunkFilename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/javascripts/sdk')
                ],
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        "sourceType": "unambiguous",
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
                        "plugins": [transformPlugin]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(html)$/,
                include: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/templates')
                ],
                use: [
                    {
                        loader : 'file-loader',
                        options : {
                            name : '[name].[ext]',
                            outputPath: 'templates/',
                        }
                    },
                    // {
                    //     loader : 'extract-loader'
                    // },
                    {
                        loader : 'html-loader',
                        options : {
                            minimize: true
                        }
                    }
                ],
                type: 'javascript/auto'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif|ico)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'url-loader',
                        options: {
                            fallback: 'file-loader',
                            limit: 500,
                            name: './images/[name].[ext]'
                        }
                    }
                ],
                type: 'javascript/auto'
            },
            {
                test: /facefinder/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                          name: '[name].[ext]',
                          outputPath: 'assets/pico/'
                        }
                    }
                ],
                type: 'javascript/auto'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(mp3|wav|wma|aac|ogg)$/,
                include: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/assets/audio')
                ],
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                          name: '[name].[ext]',
                          outputPath: 'assets/audio/'
                        }
                    }
                ],
                type: 'javascript/auto'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader : 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '[name].[ext]',
                            outputPath: 'fonts/',
                            publicPath: '../'
                        }
                    }
                ],
                type: 'javascript/auto'
            },
            {
                test: /ui-sortable/,
                use: ['imports-loader?$UI=jquery-ui/ui/widgets/sortable']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(csv|tsv)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader : 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name (file){
                                return  '[name].[ext]';
                            },
                            outputPath: 'csv/'
                        }
                    }
                ],
                type: 'javascript/auto'
            }
        ]
    },
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
          chunks: 'async',
          minSize: 20000,
          minRemainingSize: 0,
          minChunks: 1,
          maxAsyncRequests: 30,
          maxInitialRequests: 30,
          enforceSizeThreshold: 50000,
          cacheGroups: {
            defaultVendors: {
              test: '/[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/',
              priority: -10,
              reuseExistingChunk: true,
            },
            default: {
              minChunks: 2,
              priority: -20,
              reuseExistingChunk: true,
            },
          },
        },
      }
};
```

Updated webpack.dev.js

```
const {merge} = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('../../webpack.common.js');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const config=require('./dev-config.js');

module.exports = merge(common, {
    devtool: 'eval',
    devServer: {
        static: './dist',
        //hot: true
    },
    plugins:[
        //new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin(config)
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    optimization : {
        moduleIds: 'named',
    }
});
```

Im getting many errors like below in console without doing any change in code(html and controller files)

```
Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 0-0 [\] in expression [\"initUserAuthenticationForEmail()\"]
```

html at the site of error is as given below:

```
<div class="form-group text-center">
                                        <button class="btn font-weight-light btn-custom-blue btn-sm fw-300" ng-click="initUserAuthenticationForEmail()">Continue</button>
                                    </div>
```

Also my screen is not getting rendered and it's showing static html on screen along with some code as shown below:

```
// Imports import ___HTML_LOADER_GET_SOURCE_FROM_IMPORT___ from "../../node_modules/html-loader/dist/runtime/getUrl.js"; var ___HTML_LOADER_IMPORT_0___ = new URL("../images/google_new.png", import.meta.url); var ___HTML_LOADER_IMPORT_1___ = new URL("../images/ajax-loader.gif", import.meta.url); // Module var ___HTML_LOADER_REPLACEMENT_0___ = ___HTML_LOADER_GET_SOURCE_FROM_IMPORT___(___HTML_LOADER_IMPORT_0___); var ___HTML_LOADER_REPLACEMENT_1___ = ___HTML_LOADER_GET_SOURCE_FROM_IMPORT___(___HTML_LOADER_IMPORT_1___); var code = "
```

I also changes the node version from 8.16.1 to 14.17.6

Comment: You didn't do "nothing", you updated several dependencies, some even over a major version. You should look into at least each of the modules which had a major version change and look at their changelogs and what the breaking changes were. Then you can slowly figure out what parts of your code need changing.

Comment: by nothing I meant no changes in app's code, but thanks, will check, although i didn't get any build errors, just saying

Comment: Getting no build errors while upgrading from babel 6 to 7 is pure luck, I'm sorry. At least now you can narrow down any errors to modules that are in your `dependencies` and not in your `devDependencies`

Comment: Oof you just upgraded Node from 8 to 14? This will be a long day.